# Writing my own django-cms plugin. Any recommendations?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I don't see any possibility for creating a table in django-cms. I need this functionnality so I am evaluating the possibility to write my own plugin.

I am getting started with this product. I've read the documentation carefully and I see more or less how to do that.

However, I would be happy to hear some tips and tricks before starting this task. Does anybody have experience with django-cms plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on your model. Plugins use standard django admin features.

This also depends on the source data for the table.

If you have a CSV or Exel sheet as source i only would make a file field and render the file in the render function with some optional caching.

If you want to enter data by hand:

A Table model.
An Row model with a foreign key to table.

The row model can then be used as a django-admin Inline. So you can add new rows as needed.

Be aware that CMSPluginBase extends ModelAdmin so you can define inlines like you would do in normal admin.

Comment: Also, some of the wysiwyg editors (CKEditor I think) have functions for creating tables, just like in a word processor. Why not just use one of those?